# Howcome an Instance variable @variable defined in the controller's action can be called from its views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How and instance variable `@variable` defined in the controller's action can be called from its views ?

like

```
class UsersControllers
  def index
     @whythiscolavery=User.all
  end
end
```

Now in /views/users/index.html.haml why variable `@whythiscolavery`  is directly accessible in views defined in controllers action?

This query failed me in an important interview..

```
@whythiscolavery.each do   
     user.name
 end
```

Comment: I meant to ask how @variable is accessible in VIEWS defined in controller's action..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are Rails instance variables passed to views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855178/how-are-rails-instance-variables-passed-to-views)

Comment: I asked this question in 2012. so  " How are Rails instance variables passed to views?" That question is duplicate of my question.

Comment: Sorry I see how it is unfair, but it has a better answer so... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Obie Fernandez from The Rails 3 way:

> The way Rails implements controller-to-view data handoffs is through
> instance variables. Typically, a controller action initializes one or
> more instance variables. Those instance variables can then be used by
> the view.
>
> There’s a bit of irony (and possible confusion for
> newcomers) in the choice of instance variables to share data between
> controllers and views. The main reason that instance variables exist
> is so that objects (whether Controller objects, String objects, and so
> on) can hold on to data that they don’t share with other objects. When
> your controller action is executed, everything is happening in the
> context of a controller object—an instance of, say, DemoController or
> EventController. Context includes the fact that every instance
> variable in the code belongs to the controller instance.
>
> When the view template is rendered,
> the context is that of a different object, an instance of
> ActionView::Base. That instance has its own instance variables, and
> does not have access to those of the controller object.
>
> So instance
> variables, on the face of it, are about the worst choice for a way for
> two objects to share data. However, it’s possible to make it happen—or
> make it appear to happen. What Rails does is to loop through the
> controller object’s variables and, for each one, create an instance
> variable for the view object, with the same name and containing the
> same data.
>
> It’s kind of labor-intensive, for the framework: It’s like
> copying over a grocery list by hand. But the end result is that things
> are easier for you, the programmer. If you’re a Ruby purist, you might
> wince a little bit at the thought of instance variables serving to
> connect objects, rather than separate them. On the other hand, being a
> Ruby purist should also include understanding the fact that you can do
> lots of different things in Ruby—such as copying instance variables in
> a loop. So there’s nothing really un-Ruby-like about it. And it does
> provide a seamless connection, from the programmer’s perspective,
> between a controller and the template it’s rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Views are basically methods of a controller, so they can access instance variables just like a regular plain old ruby class can. If you had a class

```
class Donut
  def show
    @delicious = "very very delicious"
  end

  private
  def render_show
    "donuts are #{@delicious}"
  end
end

Donut.new.show
```

Erb (and haml, and js and all other renders) are handled in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Because in [Ruby On Rails MVC architecture](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-mvc-architecture) and ["convention over configuration"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), instance variables are crossing models/views/controllers and helpers.

Answer (score 1):

methods in a controller are public actions (unless they are protected). Instance variables assigned in that action are available in that view.

Comment: my question is just WHY SO?
(Instance variables assigned in that action are available in that view.)

Comment: I found this short description helpful, http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Ruby-on-Rails/Rails-Action-Controller/

Comment: So to answer your "How" question, "Action Controller includes a routing module that maps URLs to specific actions"

Comment: I reached upto "action", now how "views"'s index.html.haml ?

Comment: can you elaborate on "how "views"'s index.html.haml ?" , not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

The haml syntax for this would be:

```
-@whythiscolavery.each do |user|
  = user.name
```

The erb syntax would be

```
<%= @whythiscolavery.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're asking how to access the variable from the view, niiru's answer is good with the exception of an extra '=' sign in the erb syntax example. it should be:

```
<% @whythiscolavery.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

if you're asking *why it is possible that the variable is available in the view*, it's because the controller makes them available to the view (they're copied to the view). this design shortcoming (maintaining state) prompted the creation of the gem decent_exposure: https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure